# How can I participate on the Nexus 7 project as a community member?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, nexus-7

What can I do to help this project?

Answer (score 2):

You can log bugs to the bug list (found here: http://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-nexus7), help with battery/graphics benchmarking, help gather logs/data for already opened bugs, answer questions on AskUbuntu, or test the device!  If you want to help but don’t know where to start, join #ubuntu-arm on Freenode and ask for help!  Also, if you're so inclined you can submit patches to help get some of the bugs fixed!